# When does a unit test load dependent assemblies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to better understand when assemblies are loaded for Unit Testing.

I have a class (`ClassDerived`) that I am Unit Testing.  `ClassDerived` is derived from another class (`ClassBase`).

I am attempting to use the `ClassInitialize` attribute to initialize `ClassDerived` before running the first test.  The Unit Test project has a reference to both `ClassBase` and `ClassDerived`.

When executing the code in the `ClassInitialize` method, I notice that the assembly containing `ClassDerived` has not been loaded.

I determined this by looking at the return value from a call to `GetAssemblies()`.

```
var assemblies = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Oddly enough the assembly containing `ClassBase` is loaded.

I tried moving the initializing code to the Unit Test constructor with the same result.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the time-of-load is not peculiar to unit testing.  In .net 3.5, here is what I've seen:

Given an assembly 'X' that has method 'Y', and method 'Y' uses something in assembly 'Z'.

In this case, assembly 'Z' will be loaded just before method 'Y' is executed.  .net 4.0 supposely introduced greater 'laziness' on a number of fronts, so I don't know if the above observation is still true.

Comment: This is correct.  I realized it as I left work last night.  Adding a reference doesn't mean that the asembly will be loaded.  However, as soon as I used a type from that assembly in the constructor everything worked.  My Win32 experience is working against me.